# Xcode settings problem when running simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to swift programming 
I opened Xcode and changed some settings. one of which causes Xcode after exiting simulator to open ***AppDelegate*** and exit ***main.storyboard*** so I need every time to open it back again
how can I change that so after running simulator and exiting it stays at the main.storyboard screen unchanged???
thnx

Comment: Are you sure your app is not crashing on simulator and causes Xcode to show app delegate? Do you see a message when xcode displays AppDelegate?

Comment: it is not crashing the problem I changed some settings andd unfortunately don't know how to roll back them

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help you if you don't provide clues.

Comment: Can you provide screen shot? I believe your, but @rs7 is correct: Switching focus to a display of AppDelegate is often the result of a crash. Your settings changes may cause your app to crash. Only one way to tell…

Answer (score 1):

I think your app is somehow crashing and its throws you to app delegate. 
Also do check if you pu any breakpoint there. Also check you set main interface in the settings

[image]